# Do you always need to convert videos with a YUV color space for compositing in Blender?

Tags: ffmpeg, prores, colorspace, blender

I have a 10 bits .mov file with YUV color space encoded prores 422HQ of some green screen footage. -Do we always need to convert videos with a YUV color space for compositing work?

If I want to convert the footage via ffmpeg to images,I am not sure to which color space and how to convert in a right way videos with chroma subsampling of 422?

Comment: Composting in which s/w?

Comment: @Gyan Hi, I want to do the composting in blender.

Comment: Blender can use YUV video. Almost all compressed video is YUV, there are only one or two RGB codecs, so it makes sense.

Comment: @stib thank you for your answer. Regarding videos with more than 8 bits- I read that blender has a problem interpreting in a right way videos with more than 8 bits (Some places in blender, for example, the video editor will interpret 10 bit videos as 8 bit. That's why I want to convert the video to image sequences via FFMPEG. I don't know what is the right command and what is the proper image format that will maintain the highest quality as well as the proper color space and how to convert in a right way videos with chroma subsampling of 422?

Comment: @Gyan ,thank you for your answer. Regarding videos with more than 8 bits- I read that blender has a problem interpreting in a right way videos with more than 8 bits (Some places in blender, for example, the video editor will interpret 10 bit videos as 8 bit. That's why I want to convert the video to image sequences via FFMPEG. I don't know what is the right command and what is the proper image format that will maintain the highest quality as well as the proper color space and how to convert in a right way videos with chroma subsampling of 422?

Comment: What codec are you using?

Comment: @stib I tried to output the video with h.264 codec lossless, with avi or mp4 container and the result is 8 bits video.(pixel format of input video is yuv422p10le).
I came across a similar  [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73743/lossless-10-bit-colorspace-yuvj420p-video-output) and the workflow described in the comment before the last- where it is suggested
to convert the video to a 16 bit TIFF images, so that's what I'm trying to achieve now, but I don't know the proper command
to convert in the right way a YUV video with subsampling of 422 to image sequence?

Comment: Don't use h.264, wrong codec for the job. I'm not sure what codecs Blender supports, but you could try ffv1 or even prores.

Comment: Well I tried using ffv1-still 8 bits. There is no option for prores codec in blender as far as I know. I don't think I can output this video with more then 8 bits though. I would just like to learn how to convert the video to image sequence using ffmpeg and maintain the same quality?